# Material Design Icons Flicker (FOUT?)

Tags: angularjs, angular, material-design, flicker, icon-fonts

I have noticed on my angular 2 app that in IE 11 all my material design icons will flicker the text before showing the actual icon. Is there a solution to this? Is there a way to use some sort of preloader?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: FOUT: Flashing of Unstyled Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using [WebFontLoader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader)

for 'Material Icons' font. Then using CSS I was able to select and fade in all icons once they were loaded

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12171#issuecomment-595831987

Answer (score 4):

An extremely simple way to solve this is to append `display=block` to the end of the URL.

For example:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&display=block" rel="stylesheet" />
```

See the comment here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12171#issuecomment-769333603